# C++ custom console class - How to handle an object thats "<<" operator hasn't been overloaded?

Tags: c++, console

I am writing a custom console in C++ in Windows which will hopefully print out any object or at least handle every object.

Here is my WriteLine method

```
template<typename T>
inline void WriteLine(const T& t)
{
    std::cout << t << "\n";
}
```

I have an base "object" class which has an overloaded << operator as shown

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const object& object)
{
    stream << object.toString();
    return stream;
}
```

All my classes should derive from this. However, is their a way to check if a class has an overloaded << operator and if not handle it, here's what I mean.
(pseudo code)

```
template<typename T>
inline void WriteLine(const T& t)
{
    //check if the object has an overloaded << operator  
    if(itdoes){
        //then print as normal
        std::cout << t;
    }
    else {
        //if it hasn't been overloaded, just print the type of the object using <typeinfo>
        std::cout << typeid(T).name()
    }
}
```

In a nutshell I want the code to compile and handle the case when a type (T) has not been overloaded, rather than thrown a compile error. If it hasn't been overloaded just print out the objects type name
Thanks

Comment: You can write specialized, free standing, overloads of `operator <<` for those types that don't have one.

Comment: I know that but I'm wondering is there a way to allow the console class to handle a stuation where that overload isn't present? Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: @RobertGray, use SFINAE, or solve this with inheritance

Comment: If using boost you can see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/has_left_shift.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do this using [SFINAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error%20SFINAE%20on%20Wikipedia) and tag dispatch:

```
template <class T, class = void>
struct HasInserter :
  std::false_type
{};

template <class T>
struct HasInserter<T, std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<std::ostream&>() << std::declval<const T>())>> :
  std::true_type
{};


template <class T>
void WriteLine(const T &t, std::true_type)
{
  std::cout << t << '\n';
}

template <class T>
void WriteLine(const T &t, std::false_type)
{
  std::cout << typeid(T).name() << '\n';
};


template <class T>
void WriteLine(const T &t)
{
  WriteLine(t, HasInserter<T>{});
}
```

This creates a helper trait which uses SFINAE to distinguish whether the expression `stream << t` is well-formed. The trait is then used by the `WriteLine` function for tag dispatch.

Note that `std::void_t` is a C++17 feature, but it's trivial to implement in earlier versions of the standard, so the above solution can be made to work in C++11.

---

As [@mdatsev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9156061/mdatsev%20So%20user%20mdatsev) pointed out in comments, if you're using Boost, you don't have to implement the trait yourself and you can use [`boost::has_left_shift<std::ostream&, const T>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/has_left_shift.html%20Boost%20has_left_shift%20documentation) instead (with `boost::true_type` substituted for `std::true_type`, likewise with false).

Comment: Is this called detection idiom?

Comment: @Incomputable No idea; could be.

Comment: Thanks so much mate! Finally a stackoverflow user who answers a question in a helpful and clear manner, without nitt-picking about pseudo code or being generally abnoxious! Thanks again :)